# Remove Add Media and all Rich text editor buttons?

Tags: custom-post-types

I want to remove Add media from a specific post type. And I would also like to remove everything from the Rich text editor except for the box itself.
So I am only left with a clean box, no buttons, no top or bottom bar (word count).

I would like to do this for a specific post type too.

How do I manage this?

Thank you!

Comment: please ask only one question at a time. here you are asking what is obviously two unrelated questions.

Comment: ... it is probably also a good idea to explain the "why" as frankly it does not make much sense, unless you hate your users